# how to getMailer in model class

Tags: symfony-1.4, swiftmailer

I want to set up a user login process on top of sfGuardDoctrine, which sets the password to a random one. This is happening when the user is created or when his password is reset.

I figure I should centralise this routine in the sfGuardUser model class? What I can't figure out is how to get the Swiftmailer instance from there. All documentation seems to call it from within an action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the context to get access to the mailer object. This is a compose and send example that should work in your model class.

```
$sent = sfContext::getInstance()->getMailer()->composeAndSend(
              "sender_email",
              "recipient_email",
              "subject",
              "body"                   
              );
```

Comment: jeepers, I searched so hard to get the action from the context, I forgot to try to get the mailer straight up